# Can't import sqldf in one python file while it works in another. Both files are in different folders. How can I set this right?

Tags: python-2.7, importerror, sqldf, pandasql

In one python file when I try `from pandasql import sqldf` it works. The path for that is

```
C:\Users\AmitSingh\Anaconda2\python.exe "C:/Users/AmitSingh/PycharmProjects/HelloPython.py/exercise 2"
```

In another file when I use the same command it gives me the error

```
ImportError: cannot import name sqldf
```

The path for this file is

```
C:\Users\AmitSingh\Anaconda2\python.exe C:/Users/AmitSingh/Desktop/Data/Udacity/Intro_Machine_Learning/ud120-projects/datasets_questions/explore_enron_data.py
```

I don't understand why? When I write `import sqldf` the prompt shows `sqldf` as an autocomplete option. But doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

By default, you can't. When importing a file, Python only searches the current directory, the directory that the entry-point script is running from, and sys.path which includes locations such as the package installation directory (it's actually a little more complex than this, but this covers most cases).

However, you can add to the Python path at runtime:

```
# some_file.py
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/application/app/folder')

import file
```